# Why would rake assets:precompile take forever?

Tags: ruby, rake, assets, precompile

Our RoR app uses quite a few assets that need to be precompiled. It usually took several minutes for `assets:precompile` to run.

However recently something very strange happened: simple `rake assets:precompile` never ends (waited few hours).

I've found a workaround:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace
```

However it would be great to fix it anyways. Any ideas about a reason?

Comment: Have you tried `rake assets:precompile --trace`?

Comment: Oh, --trace is that's what I meant instead of --quiet. Running it with trace completes without problems. Which is weird.

Comment: If you interrupt (`Ctrl-C`) the infinite precompile perhaps the the stack trace can give some clues?

Answer (score 1):

Does it take forever on your local machine or on the production server?

I had a similar thing when I deployed my app to a AWS micro instance. It took to much CPU and then AWS limits the cpu. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

Now I precompile my assets locally and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and came across this awesome gem (by Steve Agalloco) via a gist somewhere. Anyway, works a charm!

https://github.com/spagalloco/capistrano-local-precompile